# Location consent annoyance

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, gps, app-widgets, geolocation

I use the Power Control widget shipped with Android to quickly turn GPS on and off. Since update 4.4.1 or 4.4.2, which features WiFi-based location detection, it's been pestering me for this location consent thing:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

I hit "Disagree" every single time, but it just pops right back up the next time I activate the GPS. This is extremely annoying and I'm worried I'll accidentally hit "Agree" one of these times.

How can I permanently disagree with this?

Comment: Leaving the GPS on is not an option because it's a huge battery drain.

Comment: Leaving GPS on should not be a battery drain on 4.4, if it is then it's because an app is requesting your exact location a lot.  4.4 has an option in Settings > Location as to how accurate the location provided to apps is. I have mine set to High Accuracy and I don't experience battery drain.

Comment: In the case you have root and / or are willing to obtain it. There is an Xposed module for disabling this pop-up.

Comment: Have you checked whether "network location" is disabled in *Settings*? I don't have Kitkat, so I cannot check – but with Kitkat there are at least *two* places it appears in. AFAIR second place is somewhere in WiFi settings (scanning for networks even if WiFi is turned off). As that "collection" stuff is directed at WiFi and cell-tower data (i.e. "network location"), it shouldn't apply when those are disabled, and thus make that popup disappear. As I wrote, I have no Kitkat, so I cannot verify this – which means it's purely theoretical.

Comment: @Izzy I did, it's disabled, and GPS is still a battery drain. And it's also a matter of principle. Sometimes I don't want apps I generally trust to know where I am. So for me (and probably at least some people) turning gps off is a matter of principle and right to privacy, not only power.

Comment: +1 – privacy concerns are a valid point. Though if the device is rooted (and only then), that could be solved by other means (Xprivacy or LBE for example) – which leaves it valid for non-rooted devices.

Comment: @bonanza The Xposed module you mentioned is [Disable Google Network Location consent](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.mohammadag.disablelocationconsent); it disables the dialog box, but forces you to agree to Google's background data collection, which appears to not be what OP wants.

Comment: @bmdixon: The *High Accuracy* mode you mention indeed consumes less power, but it uses WiFi and other sources along with Google data collection, [which the OP specifically wants to avoid](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61739/location-consent-annoyance/67242#comment146230_67242).

Answer (score 3):

If your device is rooted and you're using the XPosed framework, the [Deny Location Consent](http://repo.xposed.info/module/org.brainkiller.xposed.denylocationconsent) might be what you're looking for:

> Disable the annoying "Improve location accuracy?" dialog and always disagree.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it might worked as it worked in my lollipop
Goto **settings>wifi>advanced Wi-Fi**
and disable the Scanning always Available which won't use your wifi for using google location service**

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This process needs refining as it may call for disabling more items than needed:

1. Force Stop, disable, and clear cache on the following:

   - Chrome
   - Google Account Manager,
   - Google Play Services,
   - Google Play Store,
   - Google Services Framework
2. Change Location Mode: `System Settings >Location > Mode > Set to High Accuracy`
3. Re-enable the items disabled in step 1
4. Avoid consenting to Google's location service requests :)

Comment: It's possible you may only need to disable Google Services Framework in order to select high accuracy location mode with out Google consent popup getting in your way. I hope this helps get someone else started in the right direction, I know it's limited in content and purpose.

Comment: Hmm, I would have liked to see a command line version of this solution. Something like `stop blahblah.gsf` etc...

Comment: "I hit 'Disagree' every single time, but it just pops right back up the next time I activate the GPS. This is extremely annoying and I'm worried I'll accidentally hit 'Agree' one of these times."

What you're proposing is to permanently *agree* to what the OP specifically wants to *disagree* to.