# How do I get the location consent prompt back

Tags: gps, geolocation

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 and I do not mind when the location consent screen pops up when I turn on GPS, in fact I prefer it As I always choose disagree

The one that says "allow google's location service to collect anonymous data... etc "

Yesterday I hit agree and now the prompt does not come on when I turn on GPS.
In the past, if I went to location services and turned off high accuracy mode (GPS Only) it would bring back the prompt so I could disagree again.

Does anyone know how to get this prompt back (Get the dialog box back). I have tried resetting app preferences to default, disabling google app services, google play services, clearing the cache, opening location services and selecting GPS ONLY then re-enabling the google app and google apps, but nothing has worked..

I do NOT want to share anonymous information with google so I need this prompt back.
Also - Is there a way to get Location Services to default to GPS only instead of High Accuracy?

This is the opposite of THIS problem
[Location consent annoyance](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61739/location-consent-annoyance)

Comment: I tried this solution and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution found here :
[Location Consent & undo Remeber This Setting](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/84486/location-consent-undo-remeber-this-setting/138268#138268)
It did not work the first time.
The second time I left GPS only enabled with GPS on when I rebooted.
That did the trick. 
When the phone rebooted GPS was still in GPS only mode and when I turn GPS off then back on I got the "Improve location accuracy prompt again"